# Geocoder request location returns nil in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geolocation, rails-geocoder

I've been trying to get the user current location with geocoder gem but it crashes in production and returns "nil" everytime.

I've tried with a different IP, another computer, same thing...
I've tried to use .safe_location but it's nil too.

Here is my code, just in case:

```
  @location = request.safe_location

  unless @location.nil?
     @places = Place.near([@location.latitude, @location.longitude])
  end
```

Just for information, I've tried we request.location.city too. Still "no method for nil class".

I've used geocoder on 10 different apps I've coded and never had this problem. It was with Heroku everytime though, first time with AWS.

I am also using geocoder to get Place.near(params[:address]) and that works fine, so I can confirm the gem implementation is fine.

Where could that come from?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Which geocoding API are you using? It looks like there are quite a few options from the docs: https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/blob/master/README_API_GUIDE.md

Comment: I have google API. I've activated geocoding API.
But I am not sure you need to do anything with that to request.location, it does not say anything about it in the documentation. They talk about API for lookup

Comment: I've just checked and I have my API key in geocoder.rb

Answer (score 0):

These methods will usually return `nil` in test and development environments because things like `localhost` and `0.0.0.0` are not geocodable IP addresses.

Read full docs [here](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#geocoding-http-requests)